# Is it possible to create an enum from a type?

Tags: typescript, types, enums

I have a type:

```
type Type = 'EnumValueA' | 'EnumValueB'
```

I was wondering if it’s possible to create an enum from that type, for example:

```
enum Enum = {
  EnumValueA,
  EnumValueB
}
```

I am not sure if this is possible. I saw a solution to create a type from an enum, maybe this can be done too.

Thanks.

Comment: It is not possible. You can only go from enum to type.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the answer is, you can't

Comment: Enums have a runtime reification and are not *just* a type the way a union is. Typescript has a method for going from values to types (`typeof`, `keyof`) but no mechanism for going from types to values (e.g. Haskell typeclass metaprogramming).

Comment: @Liam "No" is an answer; a negative answer is not necessarily a reason to close a question.

Comment: Because of the way that you asked the question, I'm providing this as a comment instead of an answer... but I think it addresses the underlying question that you wanted to ask, which is "How can I write code that creates a numeric enum from existing data?" See this TS playground: https://tsplay.dev/w6Lz0m

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74543297/is-it-possible-to-create-an-enum-from-a-type#comment132105262_74543297) This technique allows you to define your unique string values once, in order, and then derive everything else from that readonly array. If that's what you really wanted to know, and you want to update your question, then I can write it up as an answer.

Comment: @jsejcksn I only took a quick look, but aren't you essentially reimplementing Typescript's Enum? Why wouldn't you just use an Enum? As I note in my answer, "an Enum itself already implicitly defines a type".

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74543297/is-it-possible-to-create-an-enum-from-a-type?noredirect=1#comment132115671_74543297) @Inigo If you want to take a longer look and then let me know if you still have the same thoughts, then go for it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot because Typescript types don't exist at runtime nor generate any runtime artifacts. This is called [type erasure](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/basic-types.html#erased-types).

Enums on the other hand [do](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html):

> Enums are one of the few features TypeScript has which is not a type-level extension of JavaScript.

Also, conceptually, Typescript types are used to statically describe and constrain the code, not the other way around. So it makes logical sense that you can define a Type based on an Enum and use that Type for type safety/static type checking, but it does not make sense to go the other way.

Thought experiment: Can you think of an example where it makes sense to define an Enum from a type rather than the other way around?

Remember, an Enum itself already implicitly defines a type. For example from the [Typescript documentation on Enums](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html):

```js
enum UserResponse {
  No = 0,
  Yes = 1,
}
 
function respond(recipient: string, message: UserResponse): void {
  // ...
}
```

Not only that, if the enum members are const as above, you get a [union enum](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#union-enums-and-enum-member-types) where the enum acts just like a union type.

Applying this to the example in your question and your comment below:

```js
enum Enum {
  EnumValueA,
  EnumValueB
}

interface interfaceX { a: string, b: Enum }

const x: interfaceX = { a: 'mango', b: Enum.EnumValueA }

const y: Enum = Enum.EnumValueA

x.b = y


// Because Enum is a union enum, you get the same kind of flow
// analysis and logic checking that you get with regular union
// types:
function f(arg1: Enum) {
  if (arg1 !== Enum.EnumValueA || arg1 !== Enum.EnumValueB) {
    //                            ^
    // ERROR: "This comparison appears to be unintentional because
    // the types 'Enum.EnumValueA' and 'Enum.EnumValueB' have no
    // overlap."
  }
}
```

If you want to be able to assign or pass strings ( `'EnumValueA'`) instead of enum member references (`Enum.EnumValueA`), then you can do this:

```js
// the type of arg1 will be: 'EnumValueA' | 'EnumValueB'
function f2(arg1: keyof typeof Enum) {
    // do something  
}

f2('EnumValueA')
```

Comment: Basically, I am pulling a swagger file from client to constantly get updated schemas and, using the npm package `swagger-typescript-api` converting the schemas into TS interfaces/types. Now I have all the enums as types or as values in TS interfaces. Let me know if this makes sense.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I understand, but it sounds like you have everything you need, yeah?

Comment: Well, the enums in TS interfaces are like `type Enum = 'EnumValueA' | 'EnumValueB'` or `interface {a: string, b: 'EnumValueA' | 'EnumValueB'}`, and since they are types I cannot use them like traditional enums to assign its values to a variable like `var enumA = Enum.EnumValueA`. So I was just wondering if rather than typing and creating enums from enum type if there's a better way to do it.

Comment: Does my addition to my answer (starting with "Not only that...") get you want you were after? The only difference between the examples in your comment and what I added to my answer is I'm using a real enum rather than your type composed of a union of literal values. As I point out in the answer, the real enum is a *union enum* and has all the same benefits, with the bonus that it has runtime values assignable to variables.